# Expression language: Concat String with variable in method-call

Tags: jsf

I have a backingBean with following method (signature):

```
public class SessionBean {
    ...
    public boolean subjectIsPermitted(final String permission);
    ...
}
```

In my jsf-template, I want to call this method dynamically, like this:

```
    ${sessionBean.subjectIsPermitted('company:manage:'company.id)}
```

Well, this concatenation within the method-call does throw a com.sun.el.parser.ParseException. Using "+" or "." to concat the String does not help, too.

How do I concat a String with a variable inside an EL-method-call?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Concatenating strings within EL expression defined in an attribute of a facelets tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7386133/concatenating-strings-within-el-expression-defined-in-an-attribute-of-a-facelets)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this other question:

[Combining a string with the value of a variable to be the name of another variable in EL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3129769/combining-a-string-with-the-value-of-a-variable-to-be-the-name-of-another-variab)

According to it, you can use:

```
<c:set var="variable" value="company:manage:${company.id}" />
```

before:

```
${sessionBean.subjectIsPermitted(variable)}
```

And that should work.

Regards,